# The significance of continue and break in python

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to teach myself python using a nice [online tutorial site](http://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops).

The solution I came up with was:

```
for numb in numbers:
    if numb % 2 == 0:
        print numb
    if numb == 237:
        break
```

which doesn't work and throws errors at me. The correct solution is

```
for number in numbers:
    if number == 237:
        break
    if number % 2 == 1:
        continue
    print number
```

Now this looks very similar to what I guessed the solution to be. I'm really not understanding where I went wrong and it went right.

I of course used the wrong number for `%2`, but that should just be an error in results, not in the whole thing working.

One thing I do notice is that I didn't use the word continue and I put `break` last-  I figured we do want to check 237 to see if it fits the rule and then its only numbers after it we don't want.

I also didn't use `continue` but even if I include that my code doesn't work.

What is the significance of `continue`? Why does my attempt fail?

Comment: In your version there is `number` and `numb`. `number` is not defined.

Comment: In this instance, `continue` tells the code to jump back to the start of the loop when numbers are odd (skipping the print). You should never need `continue` in a for loop, it's used to skip blocks of the loop if you don't want them executing under conditions. The reason your code errors is because of `if number == 237`, you had called your iteration variable `numb`

Comment: `continue` simply tells the script to go to the next cycle in the loop, skipping all the code which is below it. `break` tells it to get out of the loop right now and go to the code directly below it.

Comment: @sashkello got it. Incidentally it's a good idea to actually show the specific error message rather than saying the program `throws errors at me`. ETA: You changed `number` to `numb`: but you don't say whether that *fixes your error*

Comment: oops. numb/number was an error that crept in when trying to check the difference (copied and pasted bits of the solution into mine to make sure there wasn't something weird with the wrong number of spaces). It should say numb, its not the root of things.

Comment: @user3408758: In that case, could you show the actual error messages you get?

Comment: Indeed, there's absolutely nothing wrong with your code as written.

Comment: The code works as expected.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/py_compile.py", line 117, in compile
 raise py_exc
py_compile.PyCompileError: Sorry: IndentationError: ('expected an indented block', ('prog.py', 19, 13, ' break\n'))

Comment: That means your spacing is wrong in your source code. Specifically on line 19 (or the following line)

Comment: `IndentationError` means your indents are off. Don't forget they are important in python... After `:` an indented block should follow.

Comment: And uses spaces, never tabs!

Comment: ah! You need a tab after a :? I didn't realise that as its invisible. 
Copying and pasting my code from here back into my interpreter it works. Oddly enough. But having a tab after the : doesnt seem to change things. Python is an odd one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first version works fine, the continue was unnecessary:

```
>>> numbers = 2, 3, 4, 237, 5, 6
>>> for n in numbers:
...   if n % 2 == 0:
...      print(n)
...   if n == 237:
...      break
... 
2
4
```

The keyword, `continue`, aborts completion of the current iteration of the loop and *continues* the next iteration of the loop. To contrast with `break` which aborts the current iteration and stops looping entirely.